# Scaling video from MediaRecorder

Tags: html, mediarecorder

### Setup

I have a simple setup like so:

```
<video src="/myvideo.mp4" id="my-vid" preload></video>
<script>
    var chunks = [];
    var vid = document.getElementById("my-vid");
    vid.onloadeddata = function() {
        var mr = new MediaRecorder(vid.captureStream(), {
            mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=opus,vp8"
        });
        mr.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
        }
        mr.start();
        vid.play();
        vid.muted = false;
    }
    // ----
    // everything below here just downloads the file so I can
    // run it though ffprobe
    // ----
    vid.onended = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "video/webm; codecs=opus,vp8"});
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.style = "display: none;";
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = url;
            link.download = "content.webm";
            link.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

My video is 640 pixels by 360 pixels in size.

### What I want

What I want is to scale the output video so that it blows it up to 1920 by 1080 (yes, I realize it will be blocky and ugly -- that's okay. I just need the resolution to match a second video so the two can be stitched together more easily)

### What I've tried

Simply changing the `<video>` tag has no effect:

```
<video src="/myvideo.mp4" id="my-vid" preload height="1080" width="1920"></video>
```

This changes the ***display*** size, but not the ***decoded*** size (and therefore the MediaRecorder still returns a 640x360 video)

I can scale the video by using a `<canvas>` element like so:

```
<script>
    // ...
    vid.onplay = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        (function loop() {
            ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, vid.videoWidth, vid.videoHeight, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
            setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // 30 fps
        })();
    }
</script>
```

If I then use `mr = new MediaRecorder(canvas)` instead of `mr = new MediaRecorder(vid)` then I get a scaled video, but there's no audio!

Comment: If I've learned anything about HTML5 and Media Source Extensions, it's that all of the APIs are invented to solve a single corporation's business problem with no regard to future needs or flexibility or giving real power to developers. I **hate** the HTML5 video spec with a burning passion. That said, I found a way (a bad way) to do this. Using the canvas to scale the video and using a **second** MediaRecorder to grab the original 640x360 video, then writing a JavaScript WEBM parser that extract the audio from the second video and injects it into the first. Roughly 900 lines of code.

Comment: Sadly true, I have previously done something similar for non vector graphics. It feels bizarre to do it like that but since there is no other way to do it right now, it's better than nothing!